# How to open two different activities with single button?

Tags: android-studio

I have two register activity of corporate join and fresher join, but I make single login activity.

My question is that when I log in from corporate register activity, the corporate profile activity will open, but when we log in from fresher join activity, the fresher profile activity will open.

But the login page is common for both join activity.

Comment: A "destination" intent extra?

Comment: Thanks it work dude :P